# CoreTelephony - carrierName when in Airplane Mode

Tags: ios, swift, core-telephony

I have the following code to obtain the carrier name of my service provider:

```
let ctTelePhony = CTTelephonyNetworkInfo()

func cellPhoneServices() -> String {
    let serviceProvider = ctTelePhony.subscriberCellularProvider
    if let carrierName = serviceProvider?.carrierName {
        globalCarrierName = carrierName
        return carrierName}
    else {
        globalCarrierName = "Nil"
        return "Nil"}
}
```

According to documentation,`subscriberCellular`Provider was deprecated and replaced by `serviceSubscriberCellularProviders` , however when making use of that service, it returns nil.

The main question is: when I make use of the code above I get the carrier name, but when I switch to flight mode, I'm still getting my carrier name.

Is the carrier info stored locally on the phone? When making use of the `*3001#12345#*` service, all info is not displayed when if flight mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) NSString *carrierName;
```

If we configure a device for a carrier, put device in flight mode, even SIM card is removed still the device return the carrier. The carrier information might be saved inside the device somewhere securely.

> This string is provided by the carrier and formatted for presentation
>   to the user. The value does not change if the user is roaming; it
>   always represents the provider with whom the user has an account.
>
> **If you configure a device for a carrier and then remove the SIM card, this property retains the name of the carrier.**
>
> The value for this property is nil if the device was never configured
>   for a carrier.